# cannot convert ‘std::vector<ArrayIndex> (*)[2]’ to ‘std::vector<ArrayIndex>**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void getNextRowColumn(std::vector<ArrayIndex>**)’

Tags: c++, vector

I have

```
struct ArrayIndex
{
    int rowIndex;
    int columnIndex;

};
void fn()
{
    vector<struct ArrayIndex> IntermediateIndex[2];
    getNextRowColumn(&IntermediateIndex);
}
void getNextRowColumn(vector<ArrayIndex>*  IntermediateIndex[2])
{
.................
}
```

It gives error
`cannot convert ‘std::vector<ArrayIndex> (*)[2]’ to ‘std::vector<ArrayIndex>**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void getNextRowColumn(std::vector<ArrayIndex>**)’`

Comment: Yes, an array of pointers is not the same thing as a pointer to an array. What did you expect to happen? And what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want right type for getNextRowColumn argument so that I can use the same array in fn(), inside getNextRowColumn

Comment: As the error message says:   `&IntermediateIndex` is a pointer to an array of two `ArrayIndex` whereas the function function expects a pointer to a pointer.    A pointer is not an array.   The syntactic equivalence of a pointer and an array only works for one level of indirection, no more  (i.e. a pointer to an array is not the same  as a pointer to a pointer).

Comment: `std::vector<ArrayIndex> IntermediateIndex[2]` here if you trying a multidimentional array, use `std::vector< std::vector<ArrayIndex>> IntermediateIndex`. then need only a pass by ref of it. And the function `getNextRowColumn()` forward declared before `fn()`

Comment: Well, the simplest fix is to remove `&` and `*` from the code.

Comment: but that will result in copy of whole vector, is there any other way using pointers or references

Comment: It will not copy any vectors. It will simply pass a pointer.

Comment: What do you mean, "whole vector"? Your `IntermediateIndex` variable is an array (of 2 vectors), not a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to pass C array as an argument to a function then you need something like

```
void fn()
{
    vector<ArrayIndex> IntermediateIndex[2];
    getNextRowColumn(IntermediateIndex);
}

void getNextRowColumn(vector<ArrayIndex>*  IntermediateIndex)
{
}
```

But since the question is tagged `C++` you better stick to C++ semantics, for example

```
void fn()
{
    array<vector<ArrayIndex>, 2> IntermediateIndex;
    getNextRowColumn(IntermediateIndex);
}

void getNextRowColumn(array<vector<ArrayIndex>, 2>&  IntermediateIndex)
{
}
```

Or use `vector<vector<…>>`, depends on what you are going to do with it